# How to delete a resource from Hyper-v Failover Clustering using WMI in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v, failover

I have created a virtual machine in hyperV and added it into Failover clustering. Now when I delete this machine from HyperV, it remains stuck in Failover clustering. I have found a method `DeleteResource` of class `MSCluster_Resource` in `Root\MSCluster` namespace. But how can I use this method using WMI? According to Microsoft documentation, it has only one parameter as `[in] uint32 Options`. Where will I mention the resource name? How can I execute this method. 
I am using WMI classes in c# code.
I couldn't found any example of it. It will be great if anyone can share some example code for this method.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: I have called this DeleteResource() method by getting VM's management object. Now it gives me error "The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation". Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Clustered machine can be deleted using

```
virtualMachineObject.InvokeMethod("DestroyGroup", methodParameters, null);
```

where `virtualMachineObject` is a management object hold the information of a virtual machine which is to be deleted. 
Thank you!